# Using "complex" XPath in c#

Tags: c#, xpath

I have this very simple XML

```
<Customer>
   <BirthDate>1958-05-31 00:00:00</BirthDate>
</Customer>
```

I want to extract the BirthDate without the hour part.

**EDIT: It must be done in XPath statement, not in client code.**

I have this XPath tested with this [website](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi):

```
/Customer/BirthDate/substring(text(), 1, 10)
```

I also tested this XPath:

```
/Customer/BirthDate/substring(., 1, 10)
```

The website is giving me the expected result. But my C# program gives me a runtime error.

Here's the test program:

```
var content = @"<Customer><BirthDate>1958-05-31 00:00:00</BirthDate></Customer>";

using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(content)))
{
    var doc = new XPathDocument(memStream);
    var navigator = doc.CreateNavigator();

    /// GET THE "RAW" VALUE. WORKING
    var expr = navigator.Compile("/Customer/BirthDate");
    var iter = navigator.Select(expr);
    Console.WriteLine("BirthDate: {0}", iter.Current.Value);

    /// GET THE "TRANSFORMED" VALUE. NOT WORKING
    var expr2 = navigator.Compile("/Customer/BirthDate/substring(text(), 1, 8)");
    var iter2 = navigator.Select(expr2);
    Console.WriteLine("BirthDate: {0}", iter2.Current.Value);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

It's a XPathException without any innerexception with the message:

> '/Customer/BirthDate/substring(text(), 1, 10)' has an invalid token.

Wellllllll..... What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can evaluate single value like this:

```
var expr2 = navigator.Evaluate("substring(/Customer/BirthDate, 1, 10)");
Console.WriteLine(expr2);
```

But this would only get you one string.

Following expression seem to compile and return a node set, but no substring is extracted, always full string returned:

```
var expr2 = navigator.Compile("/Customer/BirthDate[substring(text(), 1, 8)]");
```

Comment: The second expression returns all the `BirthDate` nodes for which the expression within brackets is true - that in this case is all the nodes that contain any text.

Answer (score 2):

> EDIT: It must be done in XPath statement, not in client code.

The .net built-in support for XPath only supports XPath 1.0.  XPath 1.0 does not support functions in the location step, so you will have to use a third-party library for .net that supports XPath 2.0, like [XmlPrime](http://www.xmlprime.com/xmlprime/index.htm), [Saxxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/), or [Query Machine](http://qm.codeplex.com/).

Comment: XPath 1.0 does support substring function. See reference [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#strings)

Comment: @Alexander Yes, it supports that function.  However, it doesn't support functions *in a location step*.

Comment: Thanks for your XPath 2.0 library suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

i would go with your first option. Select the value, parse the string to date, then format the date. rather than do this all at once.

```
 var expr = navigator.Compile("/Customer/BirthDate");
 var iter = navigator.Select(expr);
 var formatted dates = iter
             .Select(i=>i.Current.Value)
             .Select(x => DateTime.Parse(x))
             .Select(x=> d.ToString(put desired format here))
             .ToArray();
```

Comment: I edited my question to add this precision:It must be done in XPath statement, not in client code.

Comment: you could try xslt and xml transform. that might work. but xpath is a query it filters/selects elements, it doesn't format elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
substring(/Customer/BirthDate, 1, 10)
```

that works in XPath 1.0.

As pointed out in Philip's answer the syntax you are tried is valid in XPath 2.0, but not in 1.0, that is the version supported by .NET

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you don't simply use :

```
var doc = new XPathDocument(memStream);
            var navigator = doc.CreateNavigator();

            /// GET THE "RAW" VALUE. WORKING
            var expr = navigator.Compile("/Customer/BirthDate");
            var iter = navigator.Select(expr);
            Console.WriteLine("BirthDate: {0}", iter.Current.Value);

            /// GET THE "TRANSFORMED" VALUE. NOT WORKING
            var result = iter.Current.Value.ToString().Substring(0, 10);
            Console.WriteLine("BirthDate: {0}", result);
```

put the substring value in a new var and then you will do whatever you want with it.

Comment: I edited my question to add this precision:It must be done in XPath statement, not in client code.